# Extract certain data from text file - string manipulation

Tags: python, json, regex, python-re

I am trying to process a text file and pull out all instances of Lat/Lon using python but Its been so many years since I have used it and I don't even know what to google for help. In the example below i want the Location of every start_location & end_location and then that data put into a seperate file.

```
           ""start_address"" : ""Aberdeen, SD 57401, USA"",
               ""start_location"" : {
                  ""lat"" : 45.4646954,
                  ""lng"" : -98.48596610000001
               },
               ""steps"" : [
                  {
                     ""distance"" : {
                        ""text"" : ""207 ft"",
                        ""value"" : 63
                     },
                     ""duration"" : {
                        ""text"" : ""1 min"",
                        ""value"" : 13
                     },
                     ""end_location"" : {
                        ""lat"" : 45.4641268,
                        ""lng"" : -98.48597479999999
                     },
                     ""html_instructions"" : ""Head \u003cb\u003esouth\u003c/b\u003e on \u003cb\u003eCourt St\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003e1st Ave SE\u003c/b\u003e"",
                     ""polyline"" : {
                        ""points"" : ""kyntGhpbxQhA?f@?""
                     },
```

Comment: Why are your quotes doubled?

Comment: Its just how it pulls down from the google directions API

Comment: I've used Google directions API and I get valid JSON responses all the time. The doubling must be at your end.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that this could help you: http://fredgibbs.net/tutorials/extract-geocode-placenames-from-text-file.html

As you can see in the link the person got some coordinates with a format similar to yours, as I paste in here:

```js
.
.
.
   ],
     "formatted_address" : "Albuquerque, NM, USA",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 35.2180539,
              "lng" : -106.4711629
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 34.9467659,
              "lng" : -106.881796
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 35.110703,
           "lng" : -106.609991
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 35.2180539,
              "lng" : -106.4711629
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 34.9467659,
              "lng" : -106.881796
           }           
.
.
.
```

and then processed it as a JSON with this:

```js
json = r.json()
lat = json['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
lng = json['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']
```

**Note**
This person requested the coordinates from Google, but this could be replicated for your problem